# Problems with SharePoint DelegateControl

Tags: 2013, jquery, user-controls, delegate-control

We have created a Delegated control for People Picker.

**Implementation Details:**
We have a ascx control which is using jquery Select2 plugin. This control is calling some webservice to get details.

**Problems**

1. Sometimes the delegate control does not load and default SharePoint people picker is displayed on the page.(mostly it is on first time load and not very frequent)
2. If we use the control rigorously, after some time the control converts back to normal.

We have tried almost everything from verbose logs to fiddler but not much luck finding the reason.
Please point us to the right direction or even some reasons for this.

**Edit**
After researching i found that one particular js file is not downloaded when the control does not load.
That js file is added on the ascx file as below:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Localizable="false" LoadAfterUI="true" OnDemand="true" Name="troubling.js" runat="server" />
```